# Password of Information Security

Tags: passwords

Which one of the following statements about a password is TRUE ?

- a) It must be changed only if it is compromised
- b) It cannot contain special character symbols
- c) It must be registered with the system administrator
- d) It should be changed regularly

Comment: Is this a homework question?

Comment: Nope ..its quiz

Comment: Some of these might be true on some system but not on others. Without any context it is not possible to answer.

Comment: Good - it would be a dreadful homework question...

Comment: @bandana unique questions must be asked, it's not quiz question/answer forum.

Comment: This is not a simple quiz indeed  its a  part of Information Security Awareness  programme  of a global ranking orgn.  @Shritam

Comment: @bandana information security community here has nothing to compete or answer the quizzes for the "global ranking orgn", any security awareness campaign can relay it's campaign outside the 'questions' section. It might not be a simple quiz, but it's a quiz. It looks like you hold the key already & have posted this one to measure a community of security professionals. This is how it isn't genuine.

Comment: the only practice i would recommend out of the 4 is (d)

Answer (score 2):

I hate multiple choice tests. They oversimplify complex issues to binary yes-or-no decisions which might be answered differently based on the exact circumstances. Without knowing what exact circumstances the quiz author had in mind, you often have to guess where they expect you to place your X. Such tests are in fact even *more* difficult for professionals, because the more you know about the field the test is about, the more "*if*"'s, "*but*"'s and "*it depends*" you are aware of.

> •b) It cannot contain special character symbols

That depends on the system. Some password systems can only handle a subset of possible characters. Sometimes it is required that passwords are human-readable or even human-pronounceable. But if available, it improves security against brute-force attacks if you use the largest character set the system allows.

> •a) It must be changed only if it is compromised
>
> •d) It should be changed regularly

This is a question where expert opinions differ. Everyone agrees that a password needs to be changed whenever it is compromised. But how do you know that a compromise occurred? That's why it is often recommended that passwords are changed regularly in case they were compromised without anyone noticing. But on the other hand, the more frequent you change passwords, the more often people will forget their new passwords. The password recovery process is often an Achilles heel in a secure system. It can be easily vulnerable to social engineering attacks or vulnerabilities in other systems used to authenticate the owner of an account (their email account, for example).

> •c) It must be registered with the system administrator

A well designed system doesn't require the system administrator to know any user's password ever. But not all systems are well-designed. There are some systems where any password changes must still be done through a human administrator.

Comment: Even when password changes are carried out by an administrator, they shouldn't need to know the original password. It's true that this isn't the case for all systems in practice though.